# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in custom wordpress

Tags: php

I'm having trouble resolving the issue. Getting error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array at the line below: echo ''. $brightness[0]->name .'';

```
foreach( $projectors as $projector )
{
$brightness      = get_field('brightness', $projector->ID);
$contrast        = get_field('contrast', $projector->ID);
$resolution      = get_field('native_resolution', $projector->ID);
$technology      = get_field('technology', $projector->ID);
$aspect_ratio    = get_field('aspect_ratio', $projector->ID);
$price           = get_formatted_price(get_field('price', $projector->ID));
$formatted_price = ($price == '$') ? '' : $price;

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="title">'. get_the_title($projector->ID) .'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $formatted_price .'</td>';

echo '<td>'. $brightness[0]->name .'</td>';

echo '<td>'. $contrast[0]->name .'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $resolution[0]->name .'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $technology[0]->name .'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $aspect_ratio[0]->name .'</td>';
if($projector->post_type == 'specs')
{
```

Comment: `$brightness` refers to an object instance so trying to access it as an array: `$brightness[0]` is an error. Try `$brightness->name`

Comment: Debug using `var_dump($brightness)` and see what it is? :)

Comment: use $brightness[0]['name']

Comment: Using $brightness->name worked. Thanks.  

Also, In debug mode i get this error - Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/... on line 61. While it works fine do you have any suggestions. Thanks.